# Finding all words that begin with a certain letter

Tags: regex, string, r

I'm super-rusty in both R and regular expressions. I tried reading R's regex help file but it didn't help at all!

I have a dataframe with 3 columns:

1. vocabulary, i.e., a list of the 500 most common words found in a corpus
2. count, the number of time the word appeared, and
3. probability, the count divided by the total of all word counts

The list is arranged from most to least common, so not in alphabetical order.

I need to pull out the entire row for all the words that start with the same letter. (I don't need to loop thru all the alphabet, I'll just need the results for one letter.)

I'm not just asking about regex but how to write it in R so I get the results in a new dataframe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `grep` :

```
df <- data.frame(words=c("apple","orange","coconut","apricot"),var=1:4)
df[grep("^a", df$words),]
```

Which will give :

```
    words var
1   apple   1
4 apricot   4
```

Comment: Suppose apple, orange, coconut, and apricot were all names of dataframes stored in my environment. Is there a clever way to to use the grep function as you did above to remove the dataframes with names that start with "a", e.g rm(grep code)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is useful for you.

```
# Creating some data
 set.seed(001)
    count <- sample(1:100, 6, TRUE)
    DF <- data.frame(vocabulary=c('action', 'can', 'book', 'candy', 'any','bar'),
                     count=count,
                     probability=count/sum(count)
                     )

# Spliting by the first letter
Split <- lapply(1:3, function(DF, i){
  DF[grep(paste0('^', letters[i]), DF$vocabulary),]
}, DF=DF)

Split
[[1]]
      vocabulary count probability
1     action    27  0.08307692
5        any    21  0.06461538

[[2]]
  vocabulary count probability
3       book    58   0.1784615
6        bar    90   0.2769231

[[3]]
  vocabulary count probability
2        can    38   0.1169231
4      candy    91   0.2800000
```

As you can see the result is a list, you may want to change `1:3` in lapply call by with `1:26` to take into account all the alphabet letters.

Note that the result is unodered, but this can easly done by using `orderBy` function from `doBy` package

```
 lapply(Split, function(x) orderBy(~vocabulary, data=x ))
[[1]]
  vocabulary count probability
1     action    27  0.08307692
5        any    21  0.06461538

[[2]]
  vocabulary count probability
6        bar    90   0.2769231
3       book    58   0.1784615

[[3]]
  vocabulary count probability
2        can    38   0.1169231
4      candy    91   0.2800000
```

Comment: Why not just split using `split(DF,substr(DF$vocabulary,1,1))`?